# Is there a way to pass variables into custom rest routes in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, wordpress-rest-api

I am looking for some help in creating a custom rest route in my WordPress theme.

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route( 'wpforms/v1', '/form/(?P<id>\d+)', array(
        'methods'   => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'wpforms_form_endpoint',
        'args' => array(
          'id' => array(
            'validate_callback' => 'is_numeric';
            }
          ),
        ),
    ) );
});
```

I'd like to create an endpoint for my WP API like this:

```
http://localhost/wp-json/wpforms/v1/form/5
```

And then be able to submit parameters to be processed in my `wpforms_form_endpoint` callback function. How can I grab those paramters? Do they need to be included in the arguments for the rest route, or can they passed in through a GET/POST method to the callback function?

Answer (score 1):

You'll receive the [WP_Rest_Request](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_request/) instance in your `callback`, for example:

```
function wpforms_form_endpoint($request)
{
    $id = $request->get_param('id'); // 5
}
```

Just use the `get_param` method to retrieve any parameter. Also, you can use `$request['id']`.

Comment: If you have additional parameters like `name`, `email`, and `message` do each of those need to be set as arguments in the rest route, or can they just be passed into the newly created rest route?

Comment: You have to add then in route or in `query string/$_GET`.